# sys.path.append modules relative to path of script being run

Tags: python, github

I am trying to create a github repository that can be run from any clone without hardcoding directory dependencies.

Let us say in my repo I have a python script called myscript.py and its located at:

```
/d/e/f/github/myrepo/myscript/myscript.py
```

But I know that my script depends on general utility tools always located at:

```
/d/e/f/github/myrepo/myutils/myutils.py
```

Thus, how can I tell my script to always load myutils.py, where the relative path to myutils.py with respect to myscript.py is always ../myutils/myutils.py

As of now myscript.py looks like:

```
# Import modules
import sys
sys.path.append('/d/e/f/github/myrepo/myutils/')
import myutils
```

As one can see now the fullpath to myutils.py is hardcoded, so if anyone else clones their repo in their own computer it won't work.

Ideally, users should be able to run myscript.py as follows:

```
cd /d/e/f/github/myrepo/myscript/
python myscript.py -h
```

Or,

```
python /d/e/f/github/myrepo/myscript/myscript.py -h
```

And it should work without having to hardcode the full path to the myutils module, but rather just the relative path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing some research seems this could be a possible answer:

```
# Import modules
import subprocess, sys, os
script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
myutils_path = os.path.join(script_path, '../myutils')
sys.path.append(myutils_path)
import myutils
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add the absolute path of `myutils` which is a subpackage in your project into `sys.path` because it may pollute `sys.path`.  But it's better to just add the path of `myrepo` into `sys.path`